# Объединение net framework и net core в одном проекте

Tags: .net, .net-core

Есть 2 отдельных проекта: 
Первый на net framework 4.7.2, второй на net core 2.0
Нужно объединить их в один проект.

Т.к. первый использует WinForms, а второй - уникальную библиотеку для net core, то приведение их к одному типу (в т.ч net standard невозможно).

При использовании зависимости на framework в core возникает проблема с использованием NuGet пакетов (пакеты core неправильно загружаются, зарегистрированный баг).

При  использовании зависимости на core в framework возникает ошибка:

"предназначен для целевой платформы "netcoreapp2.0". На него не следует ссылаться в проекте, предназначенном для целевой платформы ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2""

Есть возможность отключить предупреждение во втором случае, чтобы использовать оба проекта или же какое-нибудь другое решение?

Comment: Это разные рантаймы и приложение не сможет работать сразу на 2х рантаймах, поэтому и запрещает зависимость. А значит из core библиотеки нужно делать netstandard (или пересобрать под 4.7.2), а если никак, то можно глянуть на netcore 3 - там и wpf и winforms (правда еще preview)

Comment: Да, как раз в процессе поиска нашел что netcore3 поддерживает wpf, попробую перейти на него